# How do I get my retrieved image to display properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I have a MongoDB database. I can successfully upload and store images on that database using a node.js and express app. On a successful upload to the database, the response is an API url to that image.

For example, if I upload "image.png" to my database, the response message of the API upload function would be:

```json
{
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/image/image.png"
}
```

I want it so that when you follow that url, it loads that image in your browser. As in, when you click that link, that uploaded image gets displayed in your browser.

The Schema for the Image:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  img: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: { type: String, default: "image/png" },
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Image", imageSchema);
```

My `upload.js` file:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const { GridFsStorage } = require("multer-gridfs-storage");

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  options: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  file: (req, file) => {
    const match = ["image/png", "image/jpeg"];

    if (match.indexOf(file.mimetype) === -1) {
      const filename = `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`;
      return filename;
    }

    return {
      bucketName: "images",
      filename: `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`,
    };
  },
});

module.exports = multer({ storage });
```

The Image Route for the API:

```
const express = require("express");
const Image = require("../models/images");
// const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
const upload = require("../upload");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.file === undefined) return res.send("You must select a file.");

  const filename = `${Date.now()}-${req.file.originalname}`;

  const imgUrl = `http://localhost:3000/api/image/${filename}`;

  const { buffer, mimetype } = req.file;

  const data = new Image({
    name: filename,
    img: {
      data: req.file.filename,
      contentType: mimetype,
    },
  });

  try {
    // const dataToSave = await data.save();

    Image.create(data).then((err, item) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.redirect("/upload");
      }
    });

    res.status(200).json({ url: imgUrl });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.get("/:filename", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const image = await Image.find({ name: req.params.filename });

    if (!image) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Image not found" });
    }

    // res.set("Content-Type", image.img.contentType);
    // res.send(image.img.data);
    // res.render("image", items: data)
    res.render("image", { items: image });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Could not fetch image" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

In my `index.js` file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
require("dotenv").config();

const mongoString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

mongoose.connect(mongoString).then(() => {
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server started at ${3000}`);
  });
});
const database = mongoose.connection;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

database.on("error", (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});

database.once("connected", () => {
  console.log("Database Connected");
});

const imageRoute = require("./routes/imageRoute");
app.use("/api/image", imageRoute);
```

The `image.ejs` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <% items.forEach(function(image) { %>
    <div>
        <img
            src="data:image/<%=image.img.contentType%>;base64,
                    <%=image.img.data.toString('base64')%>"
        />
    </div>
    <% }) %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, when I click the link, the only thing to appear in the browser is an empty with the default image icon, not the actual image that I want displayed.